# Angular 6 - Carregar Reactive Form após requisição Http

Tags: angular, materialize

Estou com problemas para exibir uma lista de clientes obtida por uma requisição *GET* em um componente *select*. Como o *GET* é assíncrono, o formulário está sendo construído antes da requisição terminar e daí o *select* fica vazio. Se dou um refresh na página, a lista de clientes aparece.

Trecho do component:

```
form: FormGroup;
clientes: Cliente[];

constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private clienteService: ClienteService
){}

ngOnInit() {
    this.clienteService.findAll()
        .subscribe(clientes => {
            this.clientes = clientes
        });        

    this.initForm();
}

initForm(){
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        cliente: this.formBuilder.control('')
    }, { updateOn: 'blur' });
}
```

Se coloco a chamada para `initForm()` no *subscribe*, ocorre um *delay* para inicializar o formulário e assim recebo o erro:

```
ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.
```

Trecho do meu select:

```
<div class="input-field col s6">
     <select id="cliente" formControlName="cliente">
          <option disabled selected>Selecione um cliente...</option>
          <option *ngFor="let cli of clientes" [value]="cli.id">
                    {{ cli.nome }}
          </option>
      </select>
      <label for="cliente">Cliente</label>
 </div>
```

Estou usando o Angular 6 com Materialize CSS. Já tentei aplicar as soluções sugeridas nos links abaixo, mas nenhum funcionou:

https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/async-data-in-a-form-with-angular-d2506cbc1114

https://coryrylan.com/blog/using-angular-forms-with-async-data

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48747281/loading-dynamic-reactive-forms-doesnt-wait-for-the-http-call-to-complete

Comment: No form do seu HTML tem? `<form [formGroup]="form">`. Passando o olho me parece tudo certo, verifique o detalhe que te disse.

Comment: Tem sim. Não postei o código do HTML todo pois é extenso. No caso do meu service, estou trabalhando com Observable, mas já troquei para Promise e tenho o mesmo comportamento.

Comment: Acabei de fazer alguns testes aqui e ao que tudo indica, o problema não está na ordem de aquisição e exibição dos dados, mas sim com o próprio componente select do Materialize. Adicionei um `class="browser-default"` ao select e a lista de clientes agora aparece todas as vezes. O problema é que essa configuração modifica completamente o visual do formulário.

Comment: Tu chegou a tentar usar o setValue, pra inserir o valor depois que o formulario foi criado? Não to podendo testar agora mas dá uma olhada ai. Ou usar o ngIf pra ele só exibir a info quando a informação já estiver no teu array.

Comment: Tentei. Usei o setValue tanto no `ngAfterViewInit()` quanto no `ngAfterContentInit()`. Fiz um `if (this.form) { this.form.setValue({ cliente: this.clientes });}}`. Mas eu tô achando que é realmente algum bug do componente select do Materialize, pq como eu disse, com o `browser-default` não dá problema. Vou colocar o Bootstrap no projeto pra fazer alguns testes.

Comment: Posta um mini exemplo aqui pra gente ver o que fez: https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Ao que tudo indica, o componente select do Materialize está bugado. Não foi possível fazer testes mais aprofundados. Mas após fazer a troca para o Bootstrap a aplicação funcionou normalmente. Obrigado pela colaboração de todos!